# Shell can't find nginx

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, nginx, server

try to prompt this command `nginx -V` but shell returns `fish: Unknown command “nginx”`

If I try `sudo service nginx status`
I could see `Usage: /etc/init.d/nginx {start|stop|restart|reload|force-reload}`

Why `nginx -V` is not work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`/etc/init.d/nginx` is a shell script to `start/stop/...` the nginx service

```
$ file /etc/init.d/nginx
/etc/init.d/nginx: POSIX shell script, ASCII text executable
```

`nginx` binary is different and usually present in `/usr/sbin/`. Add that directory to your `PATH`.

```
$ file /usr/sbin/nginx
/usr/sbin/nginx: ELF 64-bit LSB  executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=c14e988f9696733869b790f49e27a488b0aff4c2, stripped
```

Or view the file `/etc/init.d/nginx` to find out where nginx is installed.

Comment: I found out that nginx was installed to `/opt/nginx/` How can I make add that directory to PATH?

Comment: Depends on what `shell` you are using. `export PATH=/opt/nginx:$PATH` should work.

Comment: I have used `set -U fish_user_paths /opt/nginx $fish_user_paths` but if I am entering command  `nginx -V` shell still saying `fish: Unknown command “nginx”`
`

Comment: You don't need to add the `/usr/sbin` directory to the `PATH` variable. You can access the contents of the directory `/usr/sbin` globally using the command `sudo`, `sbin` is short for **secure binary**. Example for execute `nginx` globally: `sudo nginx`

Comment: Under an old `nginx/1.14.0` version the binary was found under `/opt/nginx/sbin/nginx` on an `Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial` server.

Answer (score 0):

I had a somewhat similar issues while running `nginx -s reload` in a linux alpine docker container. I ran `cat /etc/init.d/nginx` and noticed that the scripts are using a bang openrc binary. installed openrc and voila the command works.

alpine linux cmd (not sure what ubuntu command is)

```
apk add openrc
```