# Nginx command not found, install ok

Tags: nginx

i have install Nginx with this command on Debian :

```
sudo apt install nginx
```

There is no error  during the installation. but after when i want to use Nginx command :

```
nginx -v
-bash: nginx : commande introuvable
```

`echo $PATH` :`/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin`

There is no file on /usr/local/sbin for Nginx

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Shell can't find nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36109112/shell-cant-find-nginx)

Answer (score 1):

Try it with sudo

```
sudo nginx -V
```